# is there any function/API in "vscode-extension-tester" which return the whole text from Problems Tab?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on VSCode extenshion automation where my extension is printing lot of issues in Problems Tab, and to view the whole text I need to scroll down.

But through automation there is one utility in  [vscode-extension-tester](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/wiki/ProblemsView)
problemsView.getText() to get the problems tab text.

Issue: getText(method only return the visible text, not the whole text)

Solution looking for: is there any method to get the whole text from ProblemsView Tab, or any utility to scroll the ProblemsView Tab and then get the visible Text.

```
import { BottomBarPanel} from 'vscode-extension-tester';
export async function getProblemsViewText(): Promise<string> {
    const bottomBar = new BottomBarPanel();
    const problemsView = await bottomBar.openProblemsView();
    const problems = await problemsView.getText()
    console.log(problems) // This only prints the visible text
    return problems;
}
```

const problemsView = await bottomBar.openProblemsView();
const problems = await problemsView.getText()

Expected:
const problems = await problemsView.getText()
console.log(problems) // This should prints the whole text